# Moving files owned by a different user with Sudo and wildcard

Tags: bash

I have a user named cam. Cam stores a bunch of files. Now I want to move those files so I tried the following...

```
sudo mv /home/cam/DCS-*.jpg /home/cam/cam/
```

But when I run this command I get...

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/cam/DCS-*.jpg’: No such file or directory
```

But if I runt the command like...

```
sudo mv /home/cam/DCS-934L2015110711425501.jpg /home/cam/cam/
```

It works fine. WTF am I missing

Comment: Does your user have permission to see files in `/home/cam` ? For example does this work? `ls /home/cam/DCS-*.jpg` ? (I suspect a permission denied). Will this work? `sudo sh -c 'mv /home/cam/DCS-*.jpg /home/cam/cam/'`

Comment: shouldn't sudo have permissions regardless? It is owned by a different user, but again I can copy the single file just fine. if I do a sudo ls (sudo ls /home/cam) I see everything but without sudo I don't have permissions to see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I do a `sudo ls /home/cam` I see everything but without `sudo` I don't have permissions to see anything.

When this command is executed:

```
sudo mv /home/cam/DCS-*.jpg /home/cam/cam/
```

The `*` is expanded by the shell according to the permissions of the current user. As the current user cannot see those files (`ls /home/cam` has no permission), the shell cannot expand the parameter list.

> shouldn't sudo have permissions regardless?

No. With `sudo`, the `mv` command will be executed as root, but the parameter list expansion happens before execution is passed to `sudo mv`.

To have the `*` expansion happen with root permission (so that the content of the directory will be visible), you can wrap the command in its own shell like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'mv /home/cam/DCS-*.jpg /home/cam/cam/'
```